# How to render the cards side by side (horizontally) rather than vertically in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I want to display the cards side by side but the cards are being displayed vertically.

The cards are coming one below the other. I want them side by side.

**Here's the code**

App.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "./Card";
import content from "./content";

function createEntry(entry) {
  return <Card key={entry.id} emoji={entry.emoji} back={entry.back} />;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        <span>Heading</span>
      </h1>
      {content.map(createEntry)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Card.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactCardFlip from "react-card-flip";

const CardStyle = {
  border: "1px solid #03506f",
  borderRadius: "30px",
  padding: "20px",
  margin: "20px",
  width: "270px",
  height: "170px",
  backgroundColor: "#75cfb8"
};

function Card(props) {
  const [isFlipped, setFlipped] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <ReactCardFlip isFlipped={isFlipped} flipDirection="vertical">
      <div
        style={CardStyle}
        className="CardFront"
        onClick={() => setFlipped((prev) => !prev)}
      >
        <div>
          <span className="emoji" role="img" aria-label="emojis">
            {props.emoji}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        style={CardStyle}
        onClick={() => setFlipped((prev) => !prev)}
        className="CardBack"
      >
        <p>{props.back}</p>
      </div>
    </ReactCardFlip>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

content.js

```
const content = [
  {
    id: 1,
    emoji: "",
    back:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus."
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    emoji: "",
    back:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus."
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    emoji: "",
    back:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus."
  }
];

export default content;
```

I am just a beginner to React and still in the process.
Please suggest what needs to be done to fix this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `display: inline` or use [`flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)? It's not a React issue, but a CSS issue.

Comment: Where to apply the display : inline property?   I applied to the styles.css file ----> ReactCardFlip { display : inline }     I have applied it in a wrong way I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wrap` property in `CSS flexbox` to make it responsive for **small screens**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        <span>Heading</span>
      </h1>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
        {content.map(createEntry)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It worked, just needed to add margin for proper spacing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By using CSS flex:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        <span>Heading</span>
      </h1>

      <div style={{ width: '100%', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center'}}>
         {content.map(createEntry)}
      </div>
    
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the card function in app.jsx. You can use flex

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex' }} >
   {content.map(createEntry)}
</div>
```

or

add the css to card div `display: inline`

Comment: This is also working for me but the last one in a row is getting cut.